# tailing tomcat6 webapps logs

Tags: java, logging, websocket, tomcat6

I have a webapp I've installed on tomcat6 and it doesn't work properly (jwebsocket-1.0 to be more specific). In the past I've ran this server as a java command `java jwebsocketserver.jar` and I got a good log on the console. I would like to think that it does dump some kind of a log to a file when it runs on tomcat. Is there a way I could find that file? any default location it might be in?

Comment: Did you try looking in the `tomcat6/logs` directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Logs/catalina.out
```

Tomcat logs can be found in above file.

Answer (score 0):

It should be present in `CATALINA_HOME/logs` (Tomcat installation directory/logs) folder.